# ArrayList.add works, but not ArrayList.remove

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Creating an instance of an object (o) and adding it to an Arraylist (arrayList) works fine. However, the remove function doesn't work.

```
arrayList.add(o); // works
arrayList.remove(o); // does nothing
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does `o`'s class implement `equals`? See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object))

Comment: Please add a tag for the language generally when asking question.

Comment: We'd need more information. @Vidya said it should implement equals, which is true. In addition, if you're using integers you might get incorrect behaviour ;)

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayList.remove()` look like this:

```
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
            if (elementData[index] == null) {
                fastRemove(index);
                return true;
            }
    } else {
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
                fastRemove(index);
                return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So, if your `Object` has default `equals()`, then this cant work. All object are diffrent. Add `equals()` to your `Object` class.